# Measuring elapsed time

Tags: c, time.h

I added following code to measure to learn how many milliseconds program lasted.
The problem is I get 1065 Clocks and 1065 Milli seconds. Is it normal that they are equal?
Maybe my equation is wrong which converts clock into milliseconds? Thanks in advance

```
finishClock = clock();
timeCount = finishClock - startClock ;
printf("Clocks passed: %f\n Milli Seconds passed: %f",timeCount, timeCount*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: Well, take a look at the value of CLOCKS_PER_SEC.  Good odds that it is 1000.  It is on mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `Tcl References` [here](http://tmml.sourceforge.net/doc/tcl/clock.html), they are synonymous:

> If the -option argument is -milliseconds, then the command is
>   synonymous with clock milliseconds (see below). This usage is
>   obsolete, and clock milliseconds is to be considered the preferred way
>   of obtaining a count of milliseconds.

Comment: Clock() return milliseconds then. So no conversion needed. Did I get it right?